# What is the best way to present interactive dashboards without creating a web app

Tags: python, visualization, dashboard, interactive

Recently I've been seeking ways to represent dashboards interactively.
The idea is to have a file that could be stored somewhere in the cloud and whenever someone wants to see those dashboards - just to go there and open that file(could be HTML file) and there he can find the dashboards with filters, sliders, etc.

Which is the best way to do that?
P.S. I am using python.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use bokeh or dash.  (https://demo.bokeh.org/)
Personally i use bokeh, you can generate html file with all your data and a cool and simple dataviz for exemple :https://demo.bokeh.org/movies

Comment: Thank you!
I have been working with Dash, but didn't know about the option for creating HTML files - will check on that.
Regarding Bokeh, is it possible to upload this file in let's say G drive and somebody from another location to access this file and view the dashboards without downloading it?

Comment: You are welcome, i only create html files with bokeh so you don't need any serveur. You also can create a mailing directly in python and run your script with a batch file daily.I haven't try this with dash

Comment: And when you share those Html files with other users are they working properly with all their interactivity?

Comment: Yes, maybe you had to do a bit of js but it is well documented

Comment: Have you used callbacks in your standalone files? Because as far as I can see if I want to be able to set some filters to a graph and have dropdowns I have to use a server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with filter on a stand alone file, it is what your looking for ?

First the dashboard with different pan and one filter :
[image: First the dashboard with different pan]

then the user can choose an option in the list :

[image]

and finally we display the selected option :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu :). I think this is exactly what I need. Because I didn't want to deal with server setup etc. I will check the documentation and try to use the stand-alone files created with Bokeh.

Comment: Hello, Mathieu, can you show me how did you create the dropdown? I have been trying for two days and always getting an error.

Comment: Is this with bokeh? Any pointers on how this was created?